# Watson webhook call removing messages from slack

Tags: webhooks, slack-api, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am working on Slack and watson integration. I am able to get messages from watson to slack but whenever watson calls webhook and returns message to slack, the earlier messages/conversation gets disappear.

Can some one help here?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the builtin integration
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/watson-assistant?topic=watson-assistant-deploy-slack

Comment: Thanks for replying... But I have already followed the above article. My problem is that conversation is getting removed/disappear after calling webhook